# Summernote jquery custom event callback

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am trying to get jquery custom event style callbacks to work with Summernote. The process is outlined here: https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#callbacks but thus far I can't get it to work i.e. the console doesn't say `test`. I followed the documentation but still don't understand why it isn't working.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content').summernote({
            minHeight: 225,
            toolbar: [['style', ['style']], ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']], ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']], ['insert', ['link', 'picture']], ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]]
        });
        $('#content').on('summernote.init', function () {
            console.log('test');
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="content" class="control-label">Content</label>
    <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" id="content" class="form-control automate-wysiwyg" ></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening your event listener after `summernote` has been initiated, change the order and register the event handler before the call to `summernote(...`

Comment: ok, that seems to work with `summernote.init` however it doesnt work with `$('#content').on('summernote.image.upload', function (we, files) {
            console.log('test2');
        });`

Comment: @Alex well, that's probably a different issue, maybe a specific problem with the `image.upload` handler or with the image upload mechanism itself. It seems like a subject for a different question with a different code snippet thought. If my answer solved the specific issue raised in your question, I will be happy you'll accept it. Thanks.